# Issue with adding independent filters search to multiple parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have been trying to create a report with multiple parameters. My requirement is to keep those parameters separate from each other while searching the report. [in this picture we have four input values but they are codependent which each other and the requirement says the client should be able to see the data with one filter input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eYPh.png) Can anyone can help me how to separate these individual searchers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if your parameters are related or not. If they are then please edit your question and I will update the answer.

However as a general rule you should set all parameters to allow NULL

[image]

Then in your dataset query your query would look something like

```
SELECT * 
    FROM myTable
    WHERE (
        (region IN (@region) or @region IS NULL)
        AND
        (cocode IN (@cocode) or @cocode IS NULL)
        AND
        (prodcode IN (@prodcode) or @prodcode IS NULL)
        AND
        (datetimestamp IN(@datetimestamp) or @datetimestamp IS NULL)
        )
```

I've used `IN` here in case your parameters allow multiple values, if they don't this will still work but you could change each part of the where clause to read for example, `(region = @region or @region IS NULL)`

If this does not help, please post a sample of your data and a sample of each of your parameter values, including any relationships between them.

Answer (score 0):

all these values are coming from the same table, we had to do it this way because we needed the distinct values from the table. I tried this query and report still not giving any result when I select only one parameter. SELECT * 
      FROM  data_table_name ax
      WHERE (
    (region IN (@region) or @region IS NULL) 
    AND 
    (cocode IN (@cocode) or @cocode IS NULL)
    AND 
    (prodcode IN (@prodcode) or @prodcode IS NULL)
    AND 
    (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), datetimestamp, 110) IN (@datetimestamp) or        @datetimestamp IS NULL)
    ) [This is how i structured my report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avWlY.png)

Comment: You need to delete this answer and edit your original question rather than add an answer, also please show some sample output from your table `data_table_name`